In VHDL, I have an error when slicing an unsigned result
I can't get this line of code to work:
result <= (a * b)(31 downto 16);

The compiler (ghdl) suggests there's a missing ';' after the first ')'.
a, b and result are unsigned 16 bit.
How could I fix this?
Obviously I could do the multiplication first, then slice on a new line (it's happy with that).

The prefix for the slice name here must either be an object name or a function call. Without providing a [mcve] to validate how appropriate it is you could call the function providing the operator overload as in result <= "*"(a, b)(31 downto 16); to slice the best product from the result. Chatgpt isn't authoritative here (or anywhere else without a verifiable reference). See the standard's subsection on slice names for example IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names, the normative BNF for prefix and the immediately following paragraph.

Possible duplicate of How to slice an expression in VHDL. Although that question has no answer, the comments over there provided good solutions.

It wouldn't generally be considered a duplicate of a question without an upvoted answer (wherein someone wanting to use it as a duplicate could always up vote or answer should the question meet quality guidelines with the expectation of the answer being upvoted).

This is a basic syntax issue where the OP fell short in the research effort required. The question "any suggestions?" is also too broad for stackoverflow.

Note the commented upon use of the resize function would not be appropriate here should the OP be relying on a use clause making declarations from IEEE package numeric_std directly visible. That function would truncate left elements of the result. An alternative would be to provide an intermediary signal or variable with the length of the multiply product and assign a slice of that to result.

Possible solution based on the linked question: result <= resize(shift_right(a1 * b1, result'length), result'length);. I personally would use an intermediate signal.

You can generally find the source for the as yet unnamed package providing the function resize, where you might find that resize takes the rightmost elements of the unsigned parameter which would result in truncating the best product the OP is assigning result. Your possible solution is at best speculative without a [mcve].

@LHLaurini good example why answers should not be in comments.

It looks like the answer is in this post (suggested by @LHLaurini in the comments),

Unfortunately, An expression can not be sliced:

My research effort unfortunately fell short as I simply didn't understand what the problem was to be able to find the solution myself.
Now that I understand what the problem was, I will simply have an intermediate step.

You don't provide an answer, nor do you elucidate on any intermediate step. See the BNF for slice name (8.5 Slice names in -2008). slice_name ::= prefix ( discrete_range ).  8. Names, 8.1 General prefix ::= name | function_call, "Certain forms of name (indexed and selected names, slice names, and attribute names) include a prefix that is a name or a function call. If the prefix of a name is a function call, then the name denotes an element, a slice, or an attribute, either of the result of the function call, or (if the result is an access value) of the object designated by the result."

To make matters worse the quote in the linked question is incorrect. A function call is an expression. (9. Expressions, 9.1 General, the BNF for primary). The issue here is that only a name or a function call can serve as a prefix in a slice name.

"See the BNF for slice name (8.5 Slice names in -2008)"
I would if I could find it.
"The issue here is that only a name or a function call can serve as a prefix in a slice name"
This would be a better answer to why the line of VHDL failed, but it's in the comments....

I just realised my original question was heavily edited. being new to stack exchange, I filled in all the questions in the form, it wouldn't let me post without it, hence extraneous information which was removed. however, the intent of my question was why the line of VHDL didn't work, not how to fix it (which  I already had a way of doing).
